# promote property from object destructuring argument

Tags: typescript

currently typescript has this feature

```
class Param {

    constructor(private a : string, readonly b : number) {}
}
```

when using destructure argument, need to assign manualy

```
class Option {

    private a: string;
    readonly b: number;

    constructor({a, b} : {a : string, b : number}) {

        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

is there any way to mix above example since below code does no work

```
class Mixed {

    constructor({private a , readonly b} : {a : string, b : number}) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, this is not something that is supported. If you want to assign all properties at once without having to define all of them manually you could use `Object.assign`:

```
class Option {

    private a: string;
    readonly b: number;

    constructor(object: {a: string, b: number}) {
        Object.assign(this, object);
    }
}
```

It is also possible to not specify the properties before initializing them. However, if you choose to do so, they automatically become public (without readonly). That would look like this:

```
class Option {
    
    constructor(object: {a: string, b: number}) {
        Object.assign(this, object);
    }
}
```